# How should I configure my Tor-dedicated firewall for optimum security?

Tags: linux, firewalls, proxy, tor, routing

I'm setting up a Tor-based isolating proxy using the 'Anonymizing Middlebox' iptables rules specified here: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy

i.e.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INT_IF -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INT_IF -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

...where 9040 is the Tor TransPort. The `INPUT`, `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` chains are left at the default. Would there be any merit to also including the following rules?

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Or are they rendered unnecessary by my current setup?

Are there any other firewall rules that I should consider in order to improve security and ensure that all traffic is torified?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need much more than that for a secure, functional configuration. See, for instance: [How can I block all traffic *except* Tor?](http://serverfault.com/a/434010/126632)